# Using ssh in perl script

Tags: perl, ssh

I was trying to perform password less login using ssh in perl. I am somehow stuck up with the following error message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
lost connection
```

The following was a part of my code in the perl script that threw up this error:

```
$dut_ip_addr="10.0.0.110";
system("scp run_application.sh isq\@\$dut_ip_addr\:\/home\/isq\/");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
\$dut_ip_addr
```

Why are you escaping the dollar sign? That way, Perl will not interpolate that variable for you and `scp` will try to connect to `$dut_ip_addr` which will of course fail.

There are a couple more backslashes in your code that don't make much sense. I suggest, you do something like this:

```
$dut_ip_addr = "10.0.0.110";
my $login    = "isq";
my $path     = "/home/isq/";
my $scp_command = sprintf 'scp run_application.sh %s@%s:%s', $login, $dut_ip_addr, $path;
system( $scp_command );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) and forget about all the bothersome quoting details:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($dut_ip_addr, user => 'isq');
$ssh->scp_put('run_application.sh', '/home/isq/run_application.sh');
```